# How to make a field required, based on the value of another field

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, data-annotations

I have a ViewModel with some public properties that have data annotations, like this:

```
[Required]
public string PointOfContact { get; set; }
```

Which works just fine.   I've got all of the necessary plumbing in place to display the proper control formatting and error messages when validation fails.

However, I have some fields that are *conditionally* required based on the value of a checkbox.  For example:

```
public bool Briefing { get; set; }
public DateTime BriefingTime { get; set; }
```

In this case, I only want BriefingTime to be required if the checkbox that is bound to the Briefing property is checked.  The visibility of BriefingTime is already bound to Briefing, so all I need is for it to have the usual Required behavior when the checkbox is checked.

Is there a way to do this out-of-the-box, or do I need to write my own Data Annotation class?  What would such a class look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own custom `ValidationAttribute`:

```
public class BriefingTimeRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var model = (MyModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        if (model.Briefing && !model.BriefingTime.HasValue)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("BriefingTime is required.");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this class get `Briefing` and `BriefingTime` from?

Comment: @RobertHarvey `MyModel` is assumed to be the model that you've defined those values in, by the looks of it.  This is an attribute written to handle just that one property's validation, not a generic validator for any property with a dependency on another property.

Comment: @Servy: So, `model.BriefingTime` then?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah.

Comment: `ValidationContext` is null.

Comment: Can you post full code sample please including model?

Comment: There's a lot of code in my ViewModel, but the only two relevant properties are `Briefing` and `BriefingTime`.  BriefingTime is now decorated with `[BriefingTimeRequired]`.  The ValidationResult method is firing properly, but there's nothing in `ValidationContext`.

Comment: Try overriding this property: `public override bool RequiresValidationContext { get { return true; } }` in your custom validation attribute class.

Comment: Still null.  I think this particular override of `IsValid` makes some assumptions about the way the ASP.NET page lifecycle works, assumptions that are invalid in WPF.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please show us your code for validation. Did you implement *IDataErrorInfo* or *INotifyDataErrorInfo*

Comment: @SirRufo: `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.  It is essentially [this implementation](https://github.com/Keboo/MaterialDesignInXaml.Examples/blob/master/MVVM/MVVM.Validation/AnnotationValidationViewModel.cs), *except* that I validate the entire form only when the Save button is clicked, not on individual property changes.  It works fine with the `[Required]` attribute.  My ViewModel class inherits from `AnnotationValidationViewModel`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes of course RequiredAttribute is working, because it needs no ValidationContext. The implementation is important, because now we can see that you call the [ValidationAttribute.IsValid](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.isvalid?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationAttribute_IsValid_System_Object_) method without a ValidationContext.

Comment: @SirRufo: `IsValid()` doesn't have an overload that takes a `ValidationContext` as a parameter, but I see your point.  I changed the implementation to new up a `ValidationContext` object and call [`Validate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.validate?view=netframework-4.5.2) on the attribute if `RequiresValidationContext` is set to `true`, and it now seems to be working.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The documentation tells us a different story. Please click [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.isvalid?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationAttribute_IsValid_System_Object_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationContext_) and read. You should see **IsValid(Object, ValidationContext)** (**two** arguments and the second is the **ValidationContext** and the name of the method is **IsValid**) - and look at the code of this answer - it **overrides** IsValid method

Comment: @SirRufo: That overload is not available to me in `AnnotationValidationViewModel`, my `INotifyDataErrorInfo` implementation,   because it is marked `protected`. (`AnnotationValidationViewModel` does not inherit from `ValidationAttribute`, nor should it.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey You should validate with the static [Validator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class. That is the way to call that protected IsValid method

Comment: @SirRufo: Thanks, I'll give that a look.